# Is this a real or virtual server?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

Provided the following screenshot and the suspicius Red Hat VirtIO NIC, is this server a dedicated one or a VPS (VM)?

[image: Original from http://img541.imageshack.us/img541/3420/phpinfo.jpg]
*[Click to view in original size.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3aGR.jpg)*

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Red hat virtio ethernet, qemu dvd, red hat virtio scsi. This is a VPS running KVM on the real server.

Comment: Side note - it COULD be a 1:1 virtual, i.e. it owns the whole server. Makes it easier for desaster recovery, scaling, uptime and stability (no hardware drivers).

Comment: Good point, though with only 2GB memory, I find that rather unlikely.

Comment: Agreed. More likely a small cheap virtual server.